# Running data analysis in .groupby() sections

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a current project, I am planning to perform a heteroscedasticity test for a data set consisting of the columns `Quarter`, `Policies` and `ProCon`.

I would like to perform a separate test for each individual quarter in the data set. The result I am currently receiving by using `df.groupby(['Quarter'])` however looks as follows:

```
2009Q1   [(Lagrange multiplier statistic, 1.98098210004...
2009Q2   [(Lagrange multiplier statistic, 1.98098210004...
2009Q3   [(Lagrange multiplier statistic, 1.98098210004...
2009Q4   [(Lagrange multiplier statistic, 1.98098210004...
2010Q1   [(Lagrange multiplier statistic, 1.98098210004...
2010Q2   [(Lagrange multiplier statistic, 1.98098210004...
2010Q3   [(Lagrange multiplier statistic, 1.98098210004...
```

The script is currently considering the global data, not the quarter-specific one when running through the set. Is there any smart tweak to make this a separate analysis for each quarter?

The relevant code excerpt looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("hetsca.csv")
df = df.fillna("")

def analysis(row):

    #fit regression model
    fit = smf.ols('Policies ~ ProCon', data=df).fit()

    #perform Bresuch-Pagan test
    names = ['Lagrange multiplier statistic', 'p-value', 'f-value', 'f p-value']
    test = sms.het_breuschpagan(fit.resid, fit.model.exog)

    result = lzip(names, test)
    return result

# Grouping data and assigning this as a new dataframe
newdf = df.groupby(['Quarter']).apply(analysis).to_frame(name = 'result')
newdf.to_excel('result.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could understand your question, I would suggest following edition in code

```
df = pd.read_csv("hetsca.csv")
df = df.fillna("")

def analysis(qtr, group):

    #fit regression model
    fit = smf.ols('Policies ~ ProCon', data=group).fit()

    #perform Bresuch-Pagan test
    names = ['Lagrange multiplier statistic', 'p-value', 'f-value', 'f p-value']
    test = sms.het_breuschpagan(fit.resid, fit.model.exog)

    #result = lzip(names, test)
    result = pd.DataFrame(data=[test], columns=names)
    result['Quarter']=qtr
    return result

# Grouping data and assigning this as a new dataframe
result = []
for qtr, group in df.groupby(['Quarter']):
    if len(result):
       result = pd.concat([result, analysis(qtr, group)])
    else:
       result = analysis(qtr, group)

# newdf = df.groupby(['Quarter']).apply(analysis).to_frame(name = 'result')
result.to_excel('result.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks for the great input - I have been running your edited/amended code. There is only one `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid` message left for line `result = pd.concat([result, analysis(group)])`, after that the script should hopefully run through

Comment: Actually I had worked similar task, in  which I had to process Groups from DataFrame individually. I implemented it that way. I have made one edition in for loop, please try the edited code.

Comment: I have been running the script once again. It is still yielding the error `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`. Let me check what could be the reason for that...

Comment: since test is a list I had to edit the code accordingly Now it should work, Please try

Comment: We are getting there - thanks again for your engagement. I am now seeing `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 1), indices imply (4, 4)` for line `return pd.DataFrame(data=test, columns=names)`...

Comment: It returns `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'flatten'` for line `return pd.DataFrame(data=[test.flatten()], columns=names)`

Comment: Seems like a never ending story, but thanks for your resilience ;) It is now `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.` for the same line `return pd.DataFrame(data=[[r[0] for r in test]], columns=names)`

Comment: I'm reading into solution for this right now: `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()` for line `if result:`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219917/discussion-between-kuldip-chaudhari-and-m-s).